# Anti case violation system for embedded products

Tags: embedded, security

I'm developing an embedded system that contains critical information inside. When someone tries to violate the case to obtain access to the board, the system should detect it and erase all the data needed to decrypt the file-system.

My question is about how to detect it, one thing I've already thought was to add a button in the board that is pressed when the case is closed, and will switch off when the case is opened. The problem with this approach is that if someone drills a role in the case (or some other, non standard, way to open it), the button would still be pressed and no violation would be detected.

A good solution would be to "encapsulate" the board, like a package, with some kind of mesh that will send a electrical signal when broke, so, to access the board someone would not have any option but to break the mesh and as consequence, violating the board.

I already saw some products that used a system like that, but I don't have any idea on what is the name of it, who make these meshs, or how to search for it.

Does someone knows how I can find more about it, or perhaps a better solution to the problem?

Thanks

Comment: There is no absolute security. No matter what technology you have, someone else will have better technology to defeat it. It really comes down to an economic question: Is the information you're hiding worth the effort required to get at it? The answer depends on a lot of factors, including the fact that the value of the information is different for different people. As it stands, this question is far too broad.

Comment: "I don't have any idea on what is the name of it, who make these meshs, **or how to search for it**". You don't know how to Google? Try 'anti-tamper mesh'.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, I know how to google, what I meant was what exactly words should I search to get meaningful results, the one I've tried didn't bring anything useful, note that English is not my main language, so I was unaware of the word 'anti-tamper', thanks anyway, I'm finding useful results from this.

Comment: @DaveTweed Sure, if someone has unlimited resources and unlimited time, there is no secure system that cannot be compromised, in my case, who will decide if my solution is secure enough is the government from my country since this project is for then. But to narrow the scope, I need something that would make it difficult to someone open the case and access the board without activating the violation system.

Comment: Recommended viewing: [Dave Jones tears down credit card reader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCgtTPwlDSo)

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal solution.

Some things to think about.

1. Multiple buttons. That way the case is harder to open.
2. Light sensor inside the case. If it sees light then erase.
3. Metal case that is welded or epoxied shut.
4. By strategically epoxying top and bottom of board to the case the board could be destroyed if the case is forced open.
5. Potting compound.
6. Glass pellet filled with something.